# What are the differences between Castle Monorail 3 over ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been using Castle Monorail for some years now with great success, although I haven't bothered to update the version I'm using (2 or 3 year old). Now I'm making a decision on go to ASP.Net MVC 3 or update to the latest Castle version.

I have been looking documentation on the newest version of Castle projects (specially Monorail), but there is really little or no info around (I may be wrong).

Does someone knows what are the differences between Castle Monorail version 3 over ASP.Net MVC3?

Thanks!

Comment: ASP.Net MVC is great and is only getting better, it would be my suggestion.

Comment: @Lavinski: Unless you like your frameworks opinionated, in which case FubuMVC is at least worth looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase Twain the news of the death of the Castle project has been greatly exaggerated. Dynamic Proxy, for example, is used in countless .NET projects, to many to list. It is true that the Castle Project certainly does not always hold your hand with documentation and releases, but that has never been the case. If you were happy to use it in the past then the circumstances are little different.

As for the newest version of Monorail there are some things to consider. First of all it uses a completely different pattern to Monorail 2, that is to say "Composition over inheritance". It follows similar principles to FubuMVC, OpenRasta and NancyFX, unlike MR2 and Asp.net MVC which follow a base controller pattern. Secondly, MR3 is written in F#, not C#. And thirdly there is no upgrade path from MR2 to 3.

Comment: v3 looks like a big change. Fortunately v2 is still being maintained. https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail

Answer (score 2):

Castle seems to be dead (latest blog post says "another one bites the dust....". MVC3 (4 is out soon) is very much alive and has strong team behind it. And, I believe, it has gone open-source recently.

I would switch to a project that actually has some community. Does not have to be ASP.Net MVC, but Castle does not seem to be it.

Comment: -1 Castle encompasses a lot of projects, not just MonoRail. Windsor is probably the most active and known one, but that doesn't mean that all others are dead. Have you even read the blog post you mention? I don't disagree that ASP.NET MVC has a lot more community, but the actual points you raise here are invalid...

Comment: ASPNET MVC has been open source for quite a while.  since v2, I believe: http://aspnet.codeplex.com